# IDL fails due to wrong libfreetype.6.dylib version on MacOS when called from Matlab

Tags: macos, matlab, shell, unix, idl

This is another interesting version of a libfreetype.6.dylib version incompatibility. Having figured it out, I feel it is worth documenting ...
The setup is as follows:
MacOS 10.9.5
IDL 8.3
Matlab 2013b

Matlab is used to create a shell script on the fly which in turn will call an IDL .sav file. The shell script is then called via the unix() command in Matlab.

When running the generated shell script from the shell, all works fine. When trying to run it from Matlab via the unix() command, a libfreetype.6.dylib version issue appears:

dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
Incompatible library version: libidl.8.3.dylib requires version 15.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 10.0.0

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated in other posts on similar effects but with other applications, the error message is misleading as the program evidently never tries to actually load /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib

The version of /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib can be checked via the otool:

```
otool -L libfreetype.6.dyliblibfreetype.6.dylib:

/opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.2.0)
/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.5)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

Obviously the version provided by X11 is higher than what is required by IDL.

To fix this just copy /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib into /Applications/exelis/idl83/bin/bin.darwin.x86_64

Note: the libfreetype.6.dylib does not exist in the IDL application file hierarchy at all, so, presumably, some linking with the X11 provided library version must go wrong ... fixing that would probably be a cleaner solution.